# How to swap two adjacent items in a doubly linked-list in C

Tags: c, swap, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing a program in which I need to swap two adjacent nodes in a doubly linked list using only pointers without swapping data and it doesn't work.

I've been stuck for some time. I have tried to copy some solutions found in the internet but nothing seems to work. Here is the incriminated function (where b is a->next):

```
t_chstat    *swap_node(t_chstat **a, t_chstat **b)
{
    (*a)->next = (*b)->next;
    (*b)->prev = (*a)->prev;
    (*a)->prev = (*b);
    (*b)->next = (*a);
    if ((*b)->prev != NULL)
        (*b)->prev->next = (*b);
    if ((*a)->next != NULL)
        (*a)->next->prev = (*a);
    return (*b);
}
```

When I tried to put printfs at every line to try to see what could be the problem I realized that the first instruction changes the value of (*b) and makes it (*b)->next, even though I feel like it should only change the address contained in the (*a) node. I have no idea why it does that and how to fix it.

Here is the definition of t_chstat:

```
typedef struct  s_chstat
{
    char            *path;
    struct  s_chstat    *next;
    struct  s_chstat    *prev;
}               t_chstat;
```

Comment: I cannot see why it should not work. Perhaps you could create a [mre] to show that it does not work?

Comment: Why would you pass a double pointer instead of just a pointer? Furthermore, you are just assuming that a and b are adjacent nodes. You should either check that this is the case, or better: just pass node a to the function and then b is the next node.

Comment: @Cheatah honnestly i'm a beginner and my understanding of pointers is not perfect so I thought that you had to pass double pointers if you wanted the changes not to be effective only in the stack. that's how it works when you pass a string in the parameters write? Hasn't it to be double pointer or you're juste passing a copy of the string? Anyway I put simple pointers everywhere and now it works perfectly! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (it is possible that I have missed something

```
typedef struct str_t 
{
    struct str_t *prev;
    struct str_t *next;
}str_t;

void swap(str_t *a, str_t *b)
{
    str_t *saved_prev = a -> prev;
    str_t *saved_next = a -> next;

    a -> next = b -> next;
    a -> prev = b -> prev;

    if(b -> next) (b -> next) -> prev = a;
    if(b -> prev) (b -> prev) -> next = a;

    if(saved_prev) saved_prev -> next = b;
    if(saved_next) saved_next -> prev = b;

    b -> prev = saved_prev;
    b -> next = saved_next;
}
```

Comment: I didnt test this code but I put simple pointers everywhere like you did and now it works perfectly so by looking at your code i feel like it would've probably worked too. Thanks mate!